# Scale graphics with pygame_util

Tags: pymunk

I am building a model with pymunk and I need to use real dimensions (physical size of model is approximately 1 meter). Is there a way to scale the graphics in pygame_util so that 1 meter corresponds to 800 pixels?

Answer (score 1):

Pymunk itself is unitless, as described here: http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/overview.html#mass-weight-and-units

### Pymunk 6.1 (and later)

With Pymunk 6.1 its now possible to set a Transform on the SpaceDebugDrawOptions object (or one one of the library-specific implementations like pygame_utils.DebugDraw) as documented here http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunk.html#pymunk.SpaceDebugDrawOptions.transform
With this new feature it should be possible to set a scaling Transform to achieve what you are asking about.

### Pymunk 6.0 (and earlier)

When used with pygame_util the distances will be measured in pixels, e.g. a 10x20 box shape (`create_box(size=(10,20))`) will be drawn as a 10x20 pixels rectangle. This means that the easiest way to achive what you ask about is to just define that the Pymunk length unit is 0.125cm, and therefore the box shape above 1.25cm x 2.5cm.

An alternative would be to scale the surface once complete. So instead of using the screen surface in `pymunk.pygame_util.DrawOptions()` you use a custom surface that you scale when the space has been drawn and then blit the result to the screen. I dont think this option is a good as the first option since there might be scaling artifacts, but depending on your exact use case maybe it works.

Comment: For me it is a bit strange that pygame_util don't have a "scale factor". It is most natural to model something using for example SI units to get the physics correct and then just scale the "output". By using pygame (or something else) I can perform what I want but pygame_util is a very good tool when debugging or setting up the model. 

What I really want is a good physics engine I can use with Python and then I found pymunk. I also tried Open Dynamics Engine but I didn't manage to get the Python interface to work under Windows. 

Any other open source physics engine with Python support?

Comment: I agree that it would be a useful feature. Adding a camera to the util classes (to support scale & pan) is already on the todo list.. However, no promise on when it might be added. 

Previously there were a couple of issues, e.g. using a camera would impose a little bit of performance penalty (regardless if used or not), the util drawing can not implement optimizations to only draw whats visible on screen etc.

Comment: Your question got me thinking. This is the issue for adding a "camera": https://github.com/viblo/pymunk/issues/106 Now I got a new idea about using the Transform class already included. I think that would be quite easy to implement. Would be great if you could give input what you think.

Comment: Earlier today I looked at the code and I also got the feeling that it would be easy to add scaling. I thought about adding a scale variable similar to the positive_y_is_up variable and apply scaling in the to_pygame function.

Comment: I just saw version 6.1 and tested it. It works but the radius of the circles indicating constraints are also scaled. Due to this these circles covers the whole screen and hides everything else. It seems the same is happening also with the width of the springs.